# Prove that $f(x, y, z) = x^2+y^2+z^2+2x+2y+2z+3$ is a continuous function from $R^3$ to $R$. (i.e. show that $f^{-1}$ ((a, b)) is open in $R^3$ .)

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'll start by stating I have found a very similar question already posted, but that the solution the asker has accepted isn't helping me understand what I need to do
[Prove that a function is continuous using basic open sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330217/prove-that-a-function-is-continuous-using-basic-open-sets)

As stated in the title, I'm trying to prove that $f(x, y, z) = x^2+y^2+z^2+2x+2y+2z+3$ is a continuous function from $R^3$ to $R$ by showing that $f^{-1}$ ((a, b)) is open in $R^3$.)

I fall short in finding out how to show that the following is open in $R^3$:

$f^{-1}((a,b))=\{(x,y,z): a< x^2+y^2+z^2+2x+2y+3 <b \}$

I'm really hunting for quite a detailed answer (I'll need to be able to do this sort of this for an exam in 2 days), but obvioulsy any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you know how to do a $\delta$-$\epsilon$ argument for a function of one variable? You just need to incorporate that same argument three times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $f^{-1}(a,b)=\{a<(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2+z^2+1<b\}$ thus is an open annulus. Let $x=(1,1,0)$, $U_a$ the complement of the closed ball $\bar B(x,a)$ and $U_b$ the open ball $B(x,b)$ then $f^{-1}(a,b)=U_a\cap U_b$.

Comment: Is there a proof that $f^{-1}(a,b)=\{a<(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2+z^2+1<b\}$ is open?

Comment: I have just added a proof, it is the intersection of two open subsets. The complement $U_a$ of the closed ball $\bar B((1,1,0),a)$ is open and the open ball $B((1,1,0),b)$ is open, $f^{-1}(a,b)=U_a\cap U_b$.

Comment: I have just added a proof, it is the intersection of two open subsets. The complement $U_a$ of the closed ball $\bar B((1,1,0),a)$ is open and the open ball $U_b=B((1,1,0),b)$ is open, $f^{-1}(a,b)=U_a\cap U_b$.